# Why SQL timezone conversion for Atlantic standard time is wrong?

Tags: sql-server, timezone

Atlantic standard time is (-04:00), but when I run the below query am getting (-03:00)

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEPART(tz, GETUTCDATE() AT Time Zone 'Atlantic Standard Time'), GETUTCDATE()) AS atantic_ts
```

For example:

- getutcdate() : 2022-09-12 16:00:00.000
- expected     : 2022-09-12 12:00:00.000
- Actual output: 2022-09-12 13:00:00.000

It's not giving the proper current date time of Atlantic Standard Time.

Same issue occur for some other timezones like 'Alaskan standard time' also.

Comment: What does this have to do with abstract syntax trees?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that "Atlantic Standard Time" is just the ID in the Windows time zone database, and it's highly misleading - it actually means "Atlantic Standard and Daylight Time". It basically corresponds to the IANA time zone America/Halifax as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Currently, at area is observing **ADT** (Atlantic Daylight Savings Time), which is **UTC -3 hours** - so your conversion is absolutely **correct** (for this time of year)

Comment: As you said ADT is UTC -3 hours , but AST should be UTC -4 hours. SQL Conversion is returning me -3 hours for AST also.

Comment: @JonSkeet . You are right, it is always taking Atlantic standard time conversion as "Atlantic Daylight Time". Is there anyway to get "Standard time" in SQL?

Comment: I don't know of anything that will give a constant UTC offset. I would say that it's an unusual requirement though - the result doesn't necessarily represent the actual local time anywhere in the world. It's like using UTC, but without the benefit of being UTC...

Comment: @JonSkeet There are several countries that use Atlantic Standard Time only.  There are quite a few time zones that don't switch and are configured in SQL Server that way.  For example - we have both 'US Mountain Standard Time' (no DST) and 'Mountain Standard Time' (DST).  So - for most of Arizona (except Navajo Nation) the appropriate time zone to use in SQL Server is 'US Mountain Standard Time'.

Comment: @Jeff: Ah, it's good to know there's an appropriate time zone to use. I do wish Windows time zone IDs would avoid claiming to be "standard time" when that's not what they mean :(

Answer (score 0):

FYI - you don't need to add the minutes to get to the correct time.  You can 'stack' AT TIME ZONE:

```
Declare @currentDateTime datetimeoffset = '2022-09-12 16:00:00.0000000 +00:00';  --UTC

 Select CurrentDateTime = @currentDateTime
      , ASTDateTime     = @currentDateTime At Time Zone 'Atlantic Standard Time'
      , GetUTCDateTime  = getutcdate() At Time Zone 'UTC' At Time Zone 'Atlantic Standard Time'
      , GetUTCDateTime  = cast('2022-09-12 16:00:00.000' As datetime) At Time Zone 'UTC' At Time Zone 'Atlantic Standard Time';
```

Comment: This also giving me the wrong data.  it is giving me ( -03:00 ) instead of (-04:00). Kindly check the exact date time of Atlantic time zone in google and check it with the output of this query. It is wrong.

Comment: I think you are probably using the wrong time zone - Atlantic Standard Time observes DST and is currently using the offset -03:00.  SA Western Standard Time does not observe DST and is currently using the offset -04:00.

Comment: BTW - if you check 'Atlantic Time' or 'Atlantic Daylight Time' then you find that both are using offset -03:00.  In SQL Server that time zone is using DST and therefore will change the offset.